# How can I access and change a item in Component in QML

Tags: qt, qml, components

In a Qml file ,the code like:

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    anchors.right: parent.right
    width: parent.width/2-20
    initialItem:patientdetail

    Component{
        id:patientdetail
        Column {
            id:detailcolumn
            spacing: 2
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width/2-20

            Label {
                id: label
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: qsTr("User ID")
            }

            TextField {
                id: textField_id
                readOnly: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("")
            }
        }
      }
    Component{
        id:component2
        //...other component will add to stackview
      }
   }
```

And I want to change the text of TextField by a JS function(in same file) like:

```
function updatedetail(clear,rowindex){
    if(clear){
        textField_id.text="";
    }
    else{
        textField_id.text=jsonModel1.model.get(rowindex).id;
    }
}
```

But there is a error:

> ReferenceError: textField_id is not defined

Where the error occurred？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you try to change an Object that is not yet instantiated, it will fail. But even when it is instantiated, its `id` will be in a different scope, that can't be reached like that.
This is necessary, as the same `Component` might be instantiated multiple times (e.g. as a `delegate` in a `ListView`) so it would not be unique in the context anymore.

Uppon instantiation of your `StackView`, your `Component` will be instantiated an pushed on the `StackView`. Now you have an instance and might alter exposed properties by using:

```
currentItem.textFieldText = newValue
```

in your function. For this to work you need to expose the property:

```
Component{
    id:patientdetail
    Column {
        id:detailcolumn
        spacing: 2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: parent.width/2-20

        property alias textFieldText: textField_id.text // in this context, you have access to the id. Expose it, to change it from the outside.

        Label {
            id: label
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("User ID")
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField_id
            readOnly: true
            placeholderText: qsTr("")
        }
    }
}
```

However, as the instance might be destroyed and recreated later, this change would not be permanent, so it would be better to bind the `TextField.text` to a property of an object, that will survive as long as necessary. This could be a `contextProperty` exposed from C++ or a `QtObject` passed as a model, or just a property, e.g. in the `StackView`.

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    anchors.right: parent.right
    width: parent.width/2-20
    initialItem:patientdetail

    // Change this property. The textField_id.text will be bound to it.
    property string textFieldText

    Component{
        id:patientdetail
        Column {
            id:detailcolumn
            spacing: 2
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width/2-20

            Label {
                id: label
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: qsTr("User ID")
            }

            TextField {
                id: textField_id
                readOnly: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("")
                text: stackView.textFieldText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understand, thanks for your answer. And how can I define some item(or element) that do not display in q Qml file, these item will display in stackview or swipview  when I want.

Comment: Well,I accepted. But I can't upvote, maybe I don't have enough reputation.:(